# SQL trigger with regular expression

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle10g, regex-negation

I need help with creating of trigger in Oracle DB with regular expression. I have to find a solution, when insert data is not like regular expression, it shows an error message. But I can't find, how to do it.

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IC_KONTROLA
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
OF IC_POJ
ON POJISTOVNA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
IC_KONTROLA_SPATNE EXCEPTION;
BEGIN 
IF (:NEW.IC_POJ NOT LIKE (REGEXP_LIKE (:NEW.IC_POJ,'\d{8}'))) THEN  
RAISE IC_KONTROLA_SPATNE;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN IC_KONTROLA_SPATNE THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-203, ' Identifikační číslo neodpovídá 8-číselnému vzoru!');
END;`
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Error (4,1) : PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error (4,5) : PLS-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NOT_LIKE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) syntax is off;

```
IF (:NEW.IC_POJ NOT LIKE (REGEXP_LIKE (:NEW.IC_POJ,'\d{8}'))) THEN
```

...should simply be...

```
IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (:NEW.IC_POJ,'\d{8}') THEN
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4ac7/1).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I am new in SQL especially in writting triggers, this helped me a lot! :)